# Excel conditional SUMPRODUCT using a condition of a separate column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumproduct

For an Excel spreadsheet, I am attempting to build a formula using the `SUMPRODUCT` of two columns with the condition to only use the filtered data from a separate column.

Original formula that works:

```
=(SUM(U2:U999)/(SUMPRODUCT(Q2:Q999,T2:T999)))+100%
```

I've already built the first half under the condition required but I'm having trouble conditioning the second half.

```
=SUMIFS(U:U,G:G,C4)
```

I want to condition the two columns (`Q` and `T`) used in `SUMPRODUCT` using column `G` filtered with the value in `C4`.

Comment: Pls. try this: `=(SUM(U2:U999)/SUMPRODUCT(IF(G2:G999=C4,Q2:Q999,0),IF(G2:G999=C4,T2:T999,0)))+100%`

Comment: `=(SUMIFS(U:U,G:G,C4)/(SUMPRODUCT(Q2:Q999*T2:T999*(G2:G999=C4))))+1`

Comment: @Black cat: This pushed it in the right direction. I was able to get the final result from your SUMPRODUCT(IF,()IF()). Thank you.